# OpenID stackexchange ... but I don't have a password?

Tags: discussion, bug, openid, google-openid, stack-exchange-openid

I've been using StackOverflow and other sites for quite some time now, and recently saw a 'Log in with stack exchange' link on a site.

Keen to get involved, I was taken to the page at [openid.stackexchange](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login)  ... and faced an immediate roadblock. I don't think I have a password.

I log in with Google to every stackexchange site, and consequently, I can't log in on [openid.stackexchange](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login), as there is no facility to log in with google, the site demands a password even when I am logged in on my other stack accounts. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't automatically have an account *there* if you have a Stack Exchange account. You could start by [creating one](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register).

The Stack Exchange OpenID provider is strictly speaking a separate site. It's an actual OpenID provider, and as such it would be somewhat silly if you *could* log in with, say, your Google acccount. You'd end up with some sort of daisy chain of providers; OpenID log-ins all the way down.

Comment: ah - I had assumed that like every other stackexchange site you log into it just associates with the existing sites - makes sense - thanks!